# finding database structure from phpmyadmin folder

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have an old version of a website.  I need the database structure for it but I don't appear to still have a backup that matches it though I do seem to have the 'phpmyadmin' folder.  Is there anyway to retrieve the database somewhere in the files for phpmyadmin?

Comment: Phpmyadmin is just a client to interact with MySQL databases. Isn't the website actually live already?

Comment: yes, but the site I'm trying to use is a very old version and the structure has changed a lot over that time to the extent that short of going through each function and figuring out the table structure from that it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is an application used to manage a MySQL installation, and the files in the phpMyAdmin installation folder are not related to the MySQL datadir. So in short, no, unfortunately the phpMyAdmin folder isn't going to be any help for restoring your database.